# AngularJS: How to start and stop an $interval with three cases out of several functions in one service

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently develop a track & share function with AngularJS in an Ionic and Cordova Framework as a Angular-Newcomer.

In my viewer I have several buttons, two of them should start and stop the tracking.

```
<button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="saveTakeOffTime()">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-upload"></i> <strong>TAKE-OFF</strong>
            <br ng-show="TakeOffTime" />
            <span ng-show="TakeOffTime">{{TakeOffTime | date : 'HH:mm' : 'UTC'}} UTC | {{TakeOffTime | date : 'HH:mm' : 'GMT'}} GMT</span>
        </button>

        <br />
        <button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="saveLandingTime()">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-download"></i> <strong>LANDUNG</strong>
            <br ng-show="LandingTime" />
            <span ng-show="LandingTime">{{LandingTime | date : 'HH:mm' : 'UTC'}} UTC | {{LandingTime | date : 'HH:mm' : 'GMT'}} GMT</span>
        </button>
```

As you see, they call onclick different functions as they do different things additional to save the time if the user clicks on the "TAKEOFF" or "LANDING" button.

Now I want to integrate a tracking function, I've started several approaches with functions outside of the controller, trying to check $localstorage-Variables, using $rootScope, etc. but nothing works; I ended up using a service within the Angular-module which the controller and both functions can access.

The Cases: startTracking, stopTracking and resetTracking

1) With click on TAKEOFF additional to the other function-elements an $interval should start with 60-second timer to push geolocation-data inside an array.

2) With click on LANDING that $interval should be canceled.

3) With the reset-function (no click event, will be called in some procedural cases) that $intervall should be deleted and started again.

Here's my current ".service-code in progress" where I'm ended up...

```
.service('TrackingFunctions', ['$interval', function($interval) {
        this.doTracking = function(status){
            console.log("Status: " + status);

            if(status=="startTracking"){
                var execTracking = $interval(function(){
                    console.log("exec");
                },2000);
            } else {
                $interval.cancel(execTracking);
            }
        };
    }])
```

My Question:
I have two different functions in my controllers, both having access on that service above. How can I start, stop and reset the timer with clicks on different buttons and call different action with the given "status"?
Thank you.

Comment: One easy way to handle this is with messages.  Each of the buttons, widgets, actions, rules, etc that you wish to "interact with the IntervalService" can broadcast a message into the pump and the IntervalService can register for these messages and act according to its internal rules.  Look into the documentation for `$rootScope.broadcast` to get you started and feel free to fiddle with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kalanbates/dpb5x0vf/ (The title is supposed to contain "Message Broker" but I was cursed by autocorrect)

Comment: If you do go a messaging route, I suggest that you avoid the "recipient" approach that I implemented in my fiddle.  Define the *type* of message around the purpose of the action. Try not to define your messages as "StartInterval" and "StopInterval" and "ResetInterval." The fiddly bits of the interval should be implementation details of your IntervalService and opaque to the application that is interacting with it.  A better approach would be to publish "TakeOff" and "Landing" messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiple tracking $interval:**

```
var tracker; // whenever you start a new tracker, store the reference to it. You can pass the reference to other area of the app, so they can cancel it

$scope.TAKEOFF = function TAKEOFF() { // use this instead of $scope for controllerAs
    tracker = TrackingFunctions.doTracking();
};

$scope.LANDING = function TAKEOFF() { // use this instead of $scope for controllerAs
    TrackingFunctions.doTracking(tracker);
};

function reset() {
    TrackingFunctions.doTracking(tracker); // stop the previous
    tracker = TrackingFunctions.doTracking(); // start new
};

.service('TrackingFunctions', ['$interval', function($interval) {
        this.doTracking = function(execTracking){
            if(!execTracking){ // if no tracker start new
                return $interval(function(){
                    console.log("exec");
                },2000);
            } else { // if tracker cancel
                $interval.cancel(execTracking);
            }
        };
}])
```